# Two-way Communication Using WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm designing a client-server architecture which is implemented using Windows Communication Foundation. In one of the use cases, the server needs to **request** the status of the client(s), which means it needs to call the `SendStatus()` method on the **client** and ask for its status. I was just wondering if this use case can be implemented using WCF, without creating a standalone service on the client side. I'm trying to avoid sockets because the client is a background service and is essentially always connected to the server. I understand that WCF eventually uses sockets for communication, but I'm specifically trying to use WCF since this is more like a proof of concept.

A workaround I thought of was that the client could call the `SendClientStatus()`  method on the **server** and send its status every 5 seconds or so. But then again this doesn't seem like a good approach. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's called duplex communication. [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the world of WCF, you have more or less two options.

A) [A Duplex service with Dual Http Binding](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/a-simple-duplex-service-in-wcf/)

B) A no-return-value polling scheme - this is essentially what you described. The naive implementation, as you correctly note, is not that great, but there are optimizations. Since you do not need anything returned from SendClientStatus (correct?) , you can optimize the communication by only sending an update when there is one - e.g. as long as the status of the client remains the same, nothing is sent to the server. Depending on the frequency with which client status changes, this can greatly reduce the traffic. Duplex services present some extra configuration you want to avoid unless you really need them.