# Two-Way Communication between Winforms Client and Remote XCF Service

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I have a WCF service that will be hosted on a server and a WinForms desktop application. 
I would like to implement two-way communication between them and was just after some advice on which is the best way to go about this?

I've done some looking about and the two methods I'm seeing mentioned a lot are either implementing a callback contractor using web sockets.

I'm just after some advice and guidance on which of these methods to take or if there is a better method.

Comment: You should take a loot at [signalr](http://signalr.net)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958389/two-way-communication-using-wcf/15958427#15958427

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used Callback Contract for school project  and it served it's purpose nicely. If implemented well, it transfers any kind of data between the server and client. Callback is defined the same way as Contract. It's pretty simple and I advise you to look for some examples on Code Project , like this one [Callback example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/569866/TutorialplusonplusMessageplusExchangeplusPatternsp)  , it's explained with minimum code. Also, in most books, Callback is used as an example for response from server. :)

Answer (score 0):

You tag this question as winforms, so, probably, web sockets less relevant for it.

You can use callbacks (look for [Duplex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx) for mode details).

But if you have complex functionality on both sides, and firewalls on clients are not the issue - you can create 2 wcf "services" - one will run on client machine, another one - on server. 
This will allow you to be even more flexible (for issue like server restarted, client restarted, ...)