# Can I use SignalR in my Winform c# app?

Tags: c#, signalr

I have a web service being polled every few seconds in my winform c# app. It checks for messages and gets them from my server and/or it relays messages from my desktop app to my server.

The web service is being invoke in an infinite loop which the User can stop and start at the click of a button.  When the polling is on the memory goes up and stays up (which I guess I expected using infinite loop).  If there was way for my server to notify my client that a message is available then I assume I can get rid of my infinite loop.  I was looking at different architectures and I came across SignalR but it seems more geared for asp.net. Is that the case? Or can it be modified to work in my scenario here?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two-way Communication Using WCF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958389/two-way-communication-using-wcf)

Comment: @alex-filipovici no it's not duplicate - the questions are just about similar topic

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using SignalR as a client (or server) requires win8+ to get websockets. That should be something you are very aware of before using it. I learned the hard way ;) See support here http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-1x/getting-started/supported-platforms

Comment: Hi, that IS a useful comment.  So does it fall back to long polling then do you know - which is pretty much what I am doing now.  May I ask what you decide to do?

Comment: You can run SignalR client on windows but unless you have win8 you will get other transports than websockets (SSE, long polling). This was not ok in our project, and we also needed to communicate from other systems such as RaspberryPI for example. To make a long story short we threw SignalR out and used xsockets.net instead. This is what convinced us xsockets.net/xsockets-vs-signalr

Comment: I wish I saw this article a while ago. I've now found out why our Win7 client won't speak WebSockets to Win2012 hsoted signalR service. We've chatted on jabbr - I'm still deciding whether to try and write a custom client transport or 'bin' signalR for xsockets.net

Comment: @penderi SignalR has a nice fallback mechanism when websockets is not supported. In our case we could not use SSE etc. We need ful-duplex comm and there for websockets was our only choice. Since we also needed to connect from microcontrollers the choice was easy for us. You have to do a proof of concept to see if SR or XS is right for you.

Comment: @penderi This helped us alot when adding custom functionality http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V6IUVItILjQ&list=UUaCFN2DfemnttPoGH3LLDiQ&feature=share

Answer (score 4):

See this answer about boosting asmx/WCF to become a push service in 2 lines of code. [Push Data from a WCF Service to Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265609/push-data-from-a-wcf-service-to-website)

Answer (score 1):

There is a .NET client for SignalR, also you can self host SignalR using Owin

Install package

```
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client
```