# Push Notifications From Server To Client With WCF (or similar)

Tags: wcf, websocket, push-notification, signalr, comet

I am sure that this is answered dozens of times, but I am at a loss as to what keywords to search for and thus I hope that someone can at least tell me where I should be looking given an explanation of my scenario.

I need two services (one can be just a client if that is easier) to talk to each other, but the client will be on a private network whereas the server will be on the internet.  I want to be able to push jobs to the client, but the server obviously does not have an IP to hit the client.  I'd rather not poll from the client every X seconds.  I have read various topics all circling this issue and so I am going to throw out a few terms that I think are relevant, but I am not sure which to use or exactly how.

Comet, SignalR, WebSockets, XSockets, Publisher/Subscriber Pattern...

I have looked at each of these and I am not sure which is the right way to go.  The client can certainly "subscribe" to the server on startup, so that should not be an issue.  But the client should be either a console app, windows service, or WCF service.  It seems Comet and SignalR are more for ASP.NET apps, where the client is JS in a browser.  I just need "server(client)" to server connection where the client is behind firewalls.

Which of these terms (or none of them) is a good way to handle server -> client push notifications?

Comment: I can write you a simple example if you want to? What is your scenario? Let me know. Polling is out of the question in my world. You will need full duplex communication with sockets (pub/sub)!
If you can afford to pay and do not mind sending data to hosted services you can use pubnub, pusher etc. I prefer self-hosted, but it is up to you and your needs.

Comment: I appreciate all the comments, but I was hoping more for a pattern or open source tech, than a paid service.  SignalR is looking promising...

Comment: SignalR will probably suit your needs. Just make sure that you use win8+ OS only, otherwise you will not get websockets with signalr. If you are ok with SSE, Longpolling then you can go with any OS and SignalR! Good luck

Comment: See this answer about real time WCF SignalR, XSockets etc
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19713769/2940235

Answer (score 1):

Pub/Sub architecture pattern with something like Azure Service Bus should help you create the solution you desire. This does require that service and the client are aware of the bus. For the plumbing of the client and the services use the WCF which has built in bindings to facilitate the use of this pattern.

[Azure: How to Use Service Bus Topics/Subscriptions](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions/). 
Azure SB has a counter part that works on-premises as well. There are other popular message bus tech (NServiceBus, MasTransit, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, but I am not using Azure.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [node.js](http://nodejs.org) together with [socket.io](http://socket.io).
This will give everything you need.

`socket.io` uses web sockets, and if the browser does not support web sockets, it gracefully falls back to other communication mechanism like xhr, flash, polling, aso.